# Difference between memory consumption of processes and total container memory consumption

Tags: c#, containers, openshift

I have NET 6 app in container running in OpenShift. When I query `top` inside container I see total memory consumption about 2GB. However, when I open Grafana to see what a container actually requests, I see it's close to 5GB.
This app allocates lots of big objects, so I suppose it happens because of memory fragmentation and allocations. Is that true and what tools exist for investigating this kind of issues?

[image: Grafana]

Comment: Can you post the details of what you are are seeing in Grafana? Could you be conflating container memory requests (which are defined in the pod config) and actual memory usage?

Comment: @DavidOgren requests set to 4GB, limit is 6GB. Picture added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't consider myself an expert on this topic, but since this question has been quiet for almost a week, let me give it an attempt. Others can feel to correct or update this if I make any errors.

The OpenShift metric that is getting gathered there is `container_memory_working_set_bytes` (or at least that's the default, you can see this by clicking "Show PromQL".) Whereas I expect that you were looking at memory RSS in `top`. There are lots of explanations of what the difference between [working set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set) and RSS is, and I'm not enough of a kernel expert to be definitive about all of the nuances. But my layman's explanation is that working set also will include dirty memory and other memory allocations that are not currently reclaimable.

So, that's the answer to your first question about why you are seeing a difference. It's surprising to me that the difference is so large, but since you talk about allocating lots of big objects, so perhaps that is related.

To your second question of "what tools exist for investigating these kinds of issues", essentially you can troubleshoot with your typical Linux tools. Taking a quick look at `/proc/meminfo` inside the container will give you a high level picture. If that's not enough you can use standard Linux tools like `ps` and `vmstat` (although some of those tools won't exist in stripped down container images, you may need to adjust your base image).

You could also try monitoring some additional metrics in addition to `container_memory_working_set_bytes`. The PromQL has code completion, so you can just explore the available memory metrics and see if you can find something meaningful to you to monitor. That includes `container_memory_rss`, which probably matches what you were seeing in `top`. But `container_memory_working_set_bytes` is probably the important one, since that's the one that will get a container killed for exceeding.

But that all being said, the graph image you included looks to have a healthy pattern to it: memory seems to be growing and getting reclaimed as needed. Unless you are seeing some undesirable behavior, no action might be needed.

Here are some links with more detail, although most are links to the Red Hat Portal, so you will likely need a Red Hat subscription to view them.

[Difference between memory usage on Metrics and Dashboard](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6740901)

[How is working set calculated](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4413251)

https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-3-container-resource-metrics-361c5ee46e66